# Question tag for a sentence starting with "few"

Tags: grammaticality, negation, question-tags

Which is correct?

> Few people knew the way, didn't they?
>   Few people knew the way, did they?

Comment: Same as for "nobody". But there's a difference here between "few" and "a few".

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64646/question-tags-did-you-vs-didnt-you

Comment: I would bail on this and simply write, "Few people knew the way, right?"

Comment: Why the down vote? This is a legitimate question?

Answer (score 7):

The question is difficult, because the example itself is unwieldy at best. As Peter pointed out, *few* and *a few* have opposite meanings in this context, so it would be unusual to use either where there is risk of confusion.  Since *few* here means 'not many', and simple reference to negatives gives us *Not many people knew the way, did they?*, I would say *few* also takes *did*. Conversely, *a few*, meaning 'some', would take *didn't*.  But whichever you mean, it is better to recast the sentence.

Comment: It **is** a difficult question; indeed, it made an interesting [homework exercise](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/tags.pdf) for my Intro Ling class.

Comment: +1 for recasting the sentence. English constructions like question tags aren't something that always work, are they?

Comment: There's another problem with tag questions: pitch, stress, and intonation. The second question can be asked in at least three ways with different meanings. One way asks for confirmation: "Yes, few did". One suggests the assertion is false because the speaker implies that many knew the way. One, without question intonation, declares the speaker's certainty and asks nothing: in writing it would end with a period, not a question mark.

Comment: @BillFranke: can you expand on your third point? Leaving aside that without a question mark it isn't really a tag question, I know no construction using *did they* and a full stop (apart from *did they but know it* and the like, or perhaps *"I crashed your car". "Did you."* which requires a different speaker.).

Comment: @TimLymington: You're right that it's not a tag **question** but a tag **declaration** (for want of a better word). It takes falling rather than the rising intonation common for a tag Q, which is always a yes-no Q. Some English teachers insist that despite the falling intonation, there must be a "?", but that can't be so: it doesn't reflect what was actually said. I can't point to any manual or grammar book that supports my third point, so it's possibly only an idiosyncratic notion, but I do know a few other EFL teachers who agree with it.

Comment: @BillFranke: See [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/71193/2303).

Comment: @Robusto: Thank you for the link. If punctuation has a purpose, arguing that it's _"a matter of writing style, rather than an accurate representation of exactly how it's spoken, or how it sounds"; therefore, it can't be used to differentiate between rising & falling intonations,_ negates the purpose & demands blind adherence to a "rule" that confuses the reader. No "?" means that no response is asked for or required: it's a declarative tag, not a question tag. The "?" is just a coal shovel on a diesel-driven train.

Comment: @JohnLawler Just out of curiosity, what was your Intro Ling class’ conclusion is the least impossible tag for “She may not like that, ______?”? Although quite illogical, I feel like the least problematic option to me may just be, “… would she?”. For whatever reason.

Comment: _Would_ will do; _may not_ doesn't contract, so it can't be used as a tag. Another modal will retain the infinitive _like_, and both _may_ and _would_ have roughly the same meaning. Another is _d'you think?_, which isn't the same construction type but has identical pragmatics.

Answer (score 4):

Few means almost none => implying negativity => *Did they*.

A few means, little but there is some => *Didn't they*.

> Few people knew the way, did they?
>
> A few people knew the way, didn't they?

Source: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22few+people+knew+the+way%2C+didn%27t+they%22&oq=%22&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) => [PDF document](http://radiannews.pbworks.com/f/60737188/RE-EXAM-GROUP-2-2012-GE-KEYS.pdf)

Comment: That's right. _Few_ (but not _a few_) is a [Negative Trigger](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf), and requires an affirmative tag; _a few_ is not negative and requires a negative tag.

Answer (score 2):

Few people knew the way, did they? This is a negative start, just a few up from nobody! A positive tag works well. A same-way tag (few/didn't) would not work - as NEGATIVE same-way tags are rare, and usually sound awkward.

A few people knew the way, didn't they?/ did they? Both work. As 'a few' is seen as positive, the negative tag is fine, and denotes a checking question or something closer to a statement. "A few people knew the way, didn't they!"

As positive-positive same-way tags are perfectly acceptable, the positive 'did they' tag works. Probably said in response to an earlier comment, or evidence that somebody knew the way! But it's a checking response. A few people knew the way, did they? Oh good. That's a relief.