# You have no idea, (...): "do you" or "don't you"?

Tags: negation, question-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question tags — “did you” vs. “didn’t you”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64646/question-tags-did-you-vs-didnt-you)

Which one is correct?

option 1:

> You have no idea, don't you?

or, option 2:

> You have no idea, do you?

Comment: (2) is correct and (1) is incorrect; [Tag Formation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/tags.pdf) requires an affirmative tag question after a negative declarative, however the negation is asserted.

Answer (score 10):

The general principle is that when the main clause is positive, the question tag is negative. *You have no idea* is made negative by the presence of *no*. It follows that the tag will be *do you?*

Answer (score 0):

In general "do you" since the first part of the sentence is negative (contains "no").
But sometimes natives use it wrongly "negative + negative" to highlight that situation is absolutely clear and there is no choice in the question.