# what form of grammar is the word "why" used as a pause?

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech

In this sentence:

> If you're going to take that pie I just baked, why, you've got a lot of nerve.

what role does the word "why" take? I know I've heard it in conversational speech enough to know it's legitimate, but it looks really odd in print.

Comment: heh, I agree, but it's really hard to search for something when the only clue you have is the word "why". :-)

Comment: I object to this being marked as a duplicate!  The supposed previous question that is duplicated asks WHEN the usage began.  This question is asking about the grammatical terminology for the usage.  Related, yes, but no way is this a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an exclamation (or perhaps more formally, *interjection*), either in ODO's sense 2 or OED's IV.7.b.

> **why**
>
> *exclamation*
>   **1** expressing surprise or indignation: *why, that’s absurd!*
>   **2** used to add emphasis to a response: *‘You think so?’ ‘Why, yes.’*
>
> [[ODO]](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/why)
>
> ---
>
> **why**
>
> **IV.**
>   **7.** Used interjectionally, before a sentence or clause.
>   **a.** As an expression of surprise (sometimes only momentary or slight; sometimes involving protest), either in reply to a remark or question, or on perceiving something unexpected.
>
> > 1893   M. Pemberton *Iron Pirate* i,   Mary looked up suddenly..and said,..‘Why, I believe I've been asleep!’
>
> **b.** Emphasizing or calling more or less abrupt attention to the statement following (as in the apodosis of a sentence), in opposition to a possible or vaguely apprehended doubt or objection.
>
> > 1869   G. J. Whyte-Melville *Songs & Verses* 93   So he made for the gate,..And the chain being round it, why—over he flew!
>
> [OED]

Comment: It's a [pragmatic particle](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/96766/15299), like _well, see, look, listen, now, oh, um, er, ah_. It contributes no semantic meaning to the sentence, but indicates the pragmatic interpretation that the speaker intends.